# Get the first letter of each word in a string - Unintialized string offset

Tags: arrays, foreach, concatenation

I can't understand the proposed solutions in other questions or resolve the php error Uninitialized string offset: 0 .
I used this code to create acronyme from a string

```
$article = 'the Central intelligence agency';       
$words = array('the', 'of', 'to' ); 
$pattern = '/\b(?:' . join('|', $words) . ')\b/i';
$entityWords = preg_replace($pattern, '', $article);

$words = explode(" ", $entityWords);
var_dump($words);
$entityAcro = "";
foreach ($words as $letter) {
        ->  $entityAcro .= $letter[0];
}
echo strtoupper( $entityAcro );
```

I get this result :

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 ....line (->)

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 ....line (->)

CIA

I don't understand this solution : "you must know if it exist (isset)"
I manage multiple organizations and I can't know before how many word there are inside string.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with this solution:

```
foreach ($words as $letter) {
        if(!empty($letter[0])){
            $entityAcro .= $letter[0];
        } 
    }
```

I had to verify the existence of each word $letter[0] in the array  before showing the result of the foreach condition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).